# How to deal with pass by refrence value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In a angular I have on reactive form value after submit

```
let formVal = {
                company: "sample",
                companyTag: Array [ "ADAS", "ASAS" ],
                country: "USA",
                f_name: "jhon",
                gender: "M",
                hobbies: [
                { name: "Sports", selected: true, value: "sports" },
                { name: "Travel", selected: false, value: "travel" }],
            }
```

But before sending to server these value, I have to change **formVal.hobbies** like

```
formVal.hobbies = ['sports','travel'];
```

But I want these formVal actual value for further use, but due to call by refrence properties ,where I save these(the real formVal value) is also changes.How to changes at one place but not affect other place where value is saved.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to clone the original object like this:

```js
let formVal = {
  company: "sample",
  companyTag: ["ADAS", "ASAS"],
  country: "USA",
  f_name: "jhon",
  gender: "M",
  hobbies: [{
      name: "Sports",
      selected: true,
      value: "sports"
    },
    {
      name: "Travel",
      selected: false,
      value: "travel"
    }
  ],
}

let other = Object.assign({}, formVal);
other.hobbies = ['Sports', 'Travel'];

console.log(formVal, other);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another variable to manage the new data.
You could use this `const calculatedFormVal = {...formVal, hobbies: formVal.hobbies.map(hobby => hobby.value) }` then you send this variable to the server